# SharePoint 2010 Basic Workflow Question

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've just started to look workflows in 2010 which seem pretty good but I can't find seem to find out how do something very simple.

Basically I'm creating a lost property list and workflow, essentially anyone can add a new item to the list for an item that they've found.  Next anyone can make a claim on an item in the list which should then email the admins where they can investigate and close claim if the rightful owner has claimed their item.

Should be very simple and would take me no time in .net but not in SharePoint!  Any suggestions on how I could do this?

I've been looking at SPD workflow tasks and not really getting anywhere.  My next step is to go into VS2010 but this seems overkill for such an easy task.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

what is your intention to allow someone to "claim?" are you intending to enable a "claim" as just a flag and a workflow sending emails to the admins?

Comment: The claim part of the workflow is just someone looking at the list and saying yes that's mine I'd like to collect it.  So this action would start the workflow by emailing the admins so they can call the person and make sure they are the rightful owner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Yes/No field Claimed with the default value set to false.
2. Create a SPD Workflow that would start OnItem Create.
3. In this workflow add an Action that waits till the Claimed Flag is set to true.
4. Then you can send the email to the administrator (also with an SPD activity).
5. Optionally you can delete this item from the list after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question and the fact that we tried something similar a while back, I have created a blog (my first blog entry!). Below is the link, feel free to leave comments;

http://sp10tech.blogspot.com/2010/10/creating-simple-workflow-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Idea;

Maybe use two lists. One for items lost and one for claims.  This way you can have multiple claims on each lost item.  Add a field that references the claims list so the user can select it.  Then simply have the administrators use a out of the box alert mechanism.  No need for elaborate work flow.